# Can I locate a junction box in a wall that will be accessible through a vanity cabinet?

Tags: electrical

[image: Blue Tape is possible cutout for access][image]I am remodeling a master bath and I have removed a knee wall that contained an electrical outlet. I have rerouted the wiring up next to the drain stack. I would like to locate a junction box in the new drywall behind the new vanity. I will make it accessible inside the cabinet. I will route wiring up and over about 3 feet to put an additional outlet in the wall above and to the right of the vanity.My question is..Can I locate a junction box within a foot of the under sink plumbing.[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good question; let's see what our pros respond with. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I have an outlet under my sink, this seems like the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

It looks good and accessible. The NEC doesn't say it must be *readily* accessible only accessible, in case you need to inspect or maintain it. If you are feeling like you want to help another owner or an electrician later on down the road, you might even put a label on the panel saying there is an electrical junction box behind the panel. It could save some time in the future.

Good luck.